# Periodically Accessing Twitter API: Creating Twitter Bot

Tags: python, twitter

**Problem:** 
Creating a twitter bot which will respond as soon as possible. If my account @example mentioned by @guest, then @example will reply to @guest. The idea is to create a question and answer twitter bot - like. How to parse mention and respond it, it will be a separated problem.

So I need to know when @guest mentioned @example, and then @example will reply @guest tweet as soon as possible.

**What has been done:** 
I use Mike Verdone's python twitter https://pypi.python.org/pypi/twitter/1.13.1 to compose new tweet and get the mentioned tweets. Right now, I use cron to execute this python script. So, my approach is very simple. Cron execute this script every time the cron is configured.

**Question:** 
How to solve this problem using python way (pythonic)?

Comment: Sorry mate, you need to put in some effort yourself. Show us what you've tried so far. There are numerous twitter API's out there for Python with great example. Google, try some stuff and if you need help with actual code then we'll gladly help you out :) I've got some working code here altho boundles in other stuff: https://github.com/Torxed/DHPraktikanten/blob/master/twitterapi.py and there's again, tons of other examples.

Comment: I am using Mike Verdone's Twitter API. I've written python script which will query the Twitter stream API and find which account mentioned my @example account. I executed this script using cron. So my question is: Are there any different approach besides using cron?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked into the Twitter Streaming API? This streams tweets to your application (push-based) instead of you having to poll Twitter (pull-based).

The endpoint you'd probably be most interested in: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/filter

You probably need to [setup an Twitter application](https://apps.twitter.com) to authenticate yourself through OAuth. There are plenty of open-source python libraries to make this easier for you; [here's a list maintained by Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries) (scroll down to Python and see which one feels best for your purposes).

Comment: I've successfully authenticated. I have registerd my application at https://dev.twitter.com I am using Mike Verdone's Twitter API  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/twitter I wrote a python script which will find mentioned tweets. I execute this script using cron.

Comment: @ZakiAkhmad: Are you using the [`TwitterStream`](https://github.com/sixohsix/twitter/tree/master#the-twitterstream-class) class of that library?

Comment: No, I haven't. I still use the Twitter class.

Comment: Well, try to create the TwitterStream class like so: `twitter_stream = TwitterStream(auth=your_auth_here)` and then using the statuses/filter api endpoint: `for tweet in twitter_stream.statuses.filter(track=['@example'])`

Comment: OK, will try it @Menno

Comment: still trying! I've successfully stream using statuses.sample().

Comment: Finally success! for tweet in twitter_stream.statuses.filter(track='example'): print tweet

Comment: done, and many thanks! I'am still new at stackoverflow. So still figuring out the stackoverflow features ;-)